# how to optimize this select query? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've been working on a mysql database, and one of the most important tables that have the DataBase will be between 900 and 1000 million records. Im able to do this query:

```
select MAX(SEN_ID) as SEN_ID from senal group by variable_VAR_ID
```

but it takes like 12 minutes. How can I optimize this query?

This query was working fine when the database was small, but now that there are millions of rows in the database, I am realizing I should have looked at optimizing this earlier.

The query execute within EXPLAIN show this:

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys key                key_len ref  rows     Extra
1  SIMPLE      senal index NULL          fk_senal_variable1 4       NULL 6333242  Using index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create composite index `variable_VAR_ID + SEN_ID`

Note 1: not two separated indexes, but one composite
Note 2: yes, the order matters

PS: here is a syntax description of how to create indexes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Comment: Can you explain more, so your answer becomes more useful and we learn something? Why does the order matter? Why a composite index, and not 2 separate indexes?

Comment: @Jocelyn The order matters because MySQL uses the leftmost field of a composite index first. So, in this instance, you'd want mysql to narrow down the variable_var_id to only the unique ones, then look at the SEN_ID to get the max for each unique variable_var_id. Check out this article on optimizing queries.[link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm)

Comment: So, after few hours of work, I was able to do this change: I'd created two index: `INDEX `SEN_SUPINDX` (`SEN_ID` DESC, `SEN_FECH` DESC, `variable_VAR_ID` DESC)`and `INDEX `VAR_ID` (`variable_VAR_ID` DESC)`but I dont know how to use it correctly.

Comment: table description: SEN_ID int(11), variable_VAR_ID int(10), SEN_FECH datetime, SEN_VALOR varchar(45)

Comment: @user1601753: please read "note 1". You need to have 1 composite index, not 2 separated. PS: why did you create indexes with `DESC`?!